# Super CSV (org.supercsv.io) invalid content length on Spring REST controller: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Im using Super CSV to provide REST endpoint with some data. It was working fine for a long time, but now data is too large and half of it is not delivered by Spring REST Controller. I have to set content length to make this endpoint provide all data, but I cannot find any way, how to provide correct content length. With some hardcoded value I get the whole file with Postman, but browser blocks it with error:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = "text/csv")
    public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=file.csv";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentLength(0); //how to set content length?

        ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        String[] csvHeader = {"header"};
        String[] nameMapping = {"name"};

        csvWriter.writeHeader(csvHeader);
        csvWriter.write("some object", nameMapping);

        csvWriter.close();
    }
```

nginx version: nginx/1.12.2

nginx settings:

```
location ^~ /endpoint {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution if someone needs it in future. The trick is to use reflection and set content length manually:

```
response.setContentLength(getContentLength(response));
csvWriter.close();

private int getContentLength(HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Field innerResponseField = ServletResponseWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("response");
        innerResponseField.setAccessible(true);
        innerResponseField.get(response);
        Field contentWrittenField = OnCommittedResponseWrapper.class.getDeclaredField("contentWritten");
        contentWrittenField.setAccessible(true);
        return (int) contentWrittenField.get(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```